# ​ [Kotlin/JS with React] Is there a way to use React Portals?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js

The function I suppose I should use is:

```
createPortal(
    children: ReactNode?,
    container: Element,
    key: Key? = definedExternally,
)
```

What I tried is doing something like this:

A component (Modal.kt)

```
val Modal = FC<Props> {
    p {
        +"A model modal"
    }
}
```

Then in the main App component:

```
val App = FC<Props> {
    val modalContainer = document.getElementById("menu-root") ?: error("Couldn't find menu root container!")
   createPortal(Modal.create(), modalContainer)
}
```

And in the main method:

```
fun main() {
    val container = document.getElementById("root") ?: error("Couldn't find root container!")
    createRoot(container).render(App.create())
}
```

This doesn't work however. I've tried writing something akin do what you'd write in vanilla React:

In Modal.kt

```
val modalContainer = document.getElementById("modal-root") ?: error("Couldn't find modal root!")
val modalComponent = FC<Props> {
    p {
        +"A model modal"
    }
}

val Modal = createPortal(
    modalComponent.create(),
    modalContainer
)
```

And in the main App component:

```
val App = FC<Props> {
    +Modal // Is of type ReactPortal, so you can't invoke it like a function
}
```

This doesn't work, however, so I feel pretty stuck. Would anybody be able to provide insight into this? It would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you almost had it. You need a + before the createPortal call.

```
val App = FC<Props> { _ ->
    val (showModal, setShowModal) = useState(false)
    button {
        +"Click me"
        onClick = {
            setShowModal(true)
        }
    }
    val modalContainer = document.getElementById("menu-root") ?: error("Couldn't find menu root container!")
    +createPortal(Modal.create {
        this.show = showModal
    }, modalContainer)
}

external interface ModalProps : PropsWithChildren {
    var show: Boolean
}

// not really styled like a modal, but for example
val Modal = FC<ModalProps>("Modal") { props ->
    if (props.show) {
       p {
            +"A model modal"
        }
    }
}
```